# Is this grammar {a^n b^2n | n >= 0} regular or not?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I don't understand the pumping lemma for this statment, can someone help me?

{a^n b^2n | n >= 0}

This is regular or not? If yes why, if no why?

Thanks to everybody!!

Comment: Not regular of course for the same reason as a^n b^n is not regular . A DFA has no memory other than it states so it's finite memory ... But i leave you the formal proof

Comment: Ok thank you, and is it context free? Thanks a lot

Comment: yes because Grammar :  S --> epsilon, S --> a S bb generates your language and it's of type 2 (Context Free)

Comment: Thank you so much! But, with pumping lemma for context free, can i prove that this grammar is context free? Thank you!!!

Comment: Pumping lemma will prove that the language is not regular. The grammar above proves that it's context free

Answer (score 0):

Language is not regular  if the value of n is changed the number of states in DFA will also change.In the definition of DFA to accept regular language, the set of states is a finite set. Of course the other way to prove it as non regular ,use pumping lemma for regular languages.